# Update directive on callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a google maps-directive that shows the travelling from one location to another.

During the application run, I ask the user for permission and add the current location to the scope:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $rootScope.myLocation = {}
        $rootScope.myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $rootScope.myLocation.long = position.coords.longitude;
        $rootScope.$apply()
    });
}
```

On some views, I generate a google map with a directive, based on the current location:

```
<g-map id="transit" origin="{{myLocation.lat}},{{myLocation.long}}" destination="{{location.lat}},{{location.long}}" type='TRANSIT' class="map"></g-map>
```

The problem is that if the map is generated before the user approves the location-request, google maps responses with an error (as there is no origin-location). What I want to do is have a default location as my origin, and update the google map on the callback from the browser location-api.

Is there something like a directive method that I could use? Here is my directive:

```
directive('gMap', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        origin: '@origin',
        destination: '@destination',
    },
    template: "<div id='map'></div>", 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
        var request = {
            origin: attrs.origin, 
            destination: attrs.destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[attrs.type]
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }else(
                console.log(status)
            )
        });
    }
};
```

}

Comment: I would probably wrap most of that in a Service, and use $broadcast to tell the world when the user gives permission. You could also set a default value in the Service.

Comment: I forgot about boradcast! that's a good idea, what part would you put in a service?

Comment: Any time you use $rootScope for saving data, it is a pretty good sign to be using a Service instead. Otherwise you dirty up the global scope. So the getCurrentPosition part, at least, I would slide into a Service.

Comment: Your are absolutely right, I keep finding stuff that shoud go into services, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all don't use things like this: origin="{{myLocation.lat}},{{myLocation.long}}". It's weird. That's because you never know how and when your attributes are calculated and updated. You can have different incorrect values for this. Also you need to correctly track such attributes.

Much better way is to use bi-directional binding on the scope attributes and pass the data as objects there:

```
<g-map id="transit" origin="myLocation" destination="location" type='TRANSIT' class="map"></g-map>
```

In this case you will have the directive declared as

```
...
scope: {
    origin: '=',
    destination: '=',
}
...
```

And you can have the default location specified.
Then you can easily watch over the origin and update the result.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the default values before calling `getCurrentPosition()`...

```
$rootScope.myLocation = {lat: 47, long: 120};
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $rootScope.myLocation.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $rootScope.myLocation.long = position.coords.longitude;
        $rootScope.$apply()
    });
}
```

Inside `link` in the directive, set up a watch on `origin` and `destination`...

```
function updateMap (newValue) {
    // move your map update code here and position the map to newValue
}
scope.$watch('origin', updateMap);
scope.$watch('destination', updateMap);
```

Simplified example here... http://jsbin.com/sanuhoje/1/edit?html,js,output